# Настройка плагина OptionTree WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать изменение value и надписей в админке WP. плагин подключил в режиме темы. сейчас могу вносить изменения в файле meta-boxes и они отображаются в админке, а как сделать чтобы клиент мог добавлять кнопки и их значения из админки?

Comment: Забудь про этот [труп](https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) и делай [как положено на данный момент](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/)

Comment: Согласен с @SeVlad. Option Tree - древний, тяжёлый, и неудобный инструмент.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое.